# Не создаётся виртуальное окружение VS code, не могу понять почему?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Здравствуйте застрял на моменте создания виртуальное среды, почему то она просто не создается
Прописываю в терминал: python -m venv venv
Мне выскакивает ответ: Python
Что это означает?
Полностью вот так показывает:

```
C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Work>python -m venv venv
Python
C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Work>
```

По факту должна создаться папка venv, но этого не происходит

Comment: python как устанавливали? Если с официального сайта - ставили галку "прописать в переменные окружения" (environment или что-то в этом роде)?

Comment: Это вам виндовый питон отвечает из микрософт маркета

Answer (score 0):

Для создания виртуальной среды в Python, вы можете следовать следующим шагам:

1. Перейдите в директорию своего проекта.
2. Выполните следующую команду:

```
python -m venv venv
```

Answer (score 0):

После создания виртуального окружения нужно его активировать
Если у вас Windows:

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

Если MacOS или Linux:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

После активации окружения ваш терминал или командная строка изменятся, и вы увидите имя виртуального окружения в начале строки.

Пример:

```
(venv) user@host:~$
```

Примечание: команды выполнятся корректно если имя среды venv. Иначе, нужно изменить команды, установив название среды